# array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, int given

Tags: laravel

I am trying to insert data in *Laravel* using *DB*

code:

*web.php*

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ExamController;

Route::get('/', [ExamController::class, 'Index']);
Route::post('/exam-sub', [ExamController::class, 'Insertexam'])->name('sub')
```

*welcome.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('css/test.css') }}" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Quiz app</title> 
</head>

<body bgcolor="green">
    <form action="{{ route('sub') }}" method="post">
        @csrf 
        <div class="container mb-3">
            @if(Session::has('exam_submitted'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ Session::get('exam_submitted') }}
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="form-outline">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">First name</label>
                <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" name="first_name"/>
                @error('first_name')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="form-outline">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">SEC NAME</label>
                <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" name="sec_name"/>
                @error('sec_name')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>  

            <div class="form-outline">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">EMAIL</label>
                <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" name="email"/>
                @error('email')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>  

            <div class="form-outline">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">PASSWORD</label>
                <input type="password" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" name="password"/>
                @error('password')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <h1 class="color-grey">test</h1>
            <hr style="width: 30%; font-weight: 700; height:3px; background-color:black;">

            <div class="form-outline">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">24x90</label>
                <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" name="question1"/>
                @error('question-1')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="form-outline">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">45x80</label>
                <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" name="question2" />
                @error('question-2')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="form-outline">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">100x10</label>
                <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" name="question3"/>
                @error('question-3')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="form-outline">
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">10x10</label>
                <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" name="question4"/>
                @error('question-4')
                    <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-lg">Submit test</button>
        </div>
    </form>
       
    <div class="btn"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-SR1sx49pcuLnqZUnnPwx6FCym0wLsk5JZuNx2bPPENzswTNFaQU1RDvt3wT4gWFG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

*ExamController*

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ExamController extends Controller
{
    public function Index() {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function Insertexam(Request $request) {
        $validatedata = $request->validate([
            'id' => mt_rand(1, 1000),
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'sec_name' => 'required',
            'email'=> 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|max:24',
            'question-1' => 'required|int',
            'question-2' => 'required|int',
            'question-3' => 'required|int',
            'question-4' => 'required|int',
        ]);

        DB::table('exam')->insert([
            'Firstname' => $request->first_name,
            'Secondname' => $request->body,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'question1' => $request->question1,
            'question2' => $request->question2,
            'question3' => $request->question3,
            'question4' => $request->question4,
        ]);

        return back()->with('exam_submitted','Exam submitted successfully contact you mr for the results good luck');
    }
}
```

The problem is when inserting data it shows this:
`array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, int given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this 'id' => mt_rand(1, 1000), try to remove it.

```
$validatedata = $request->validate([
               'id' => mt_rand(1, 1000),
                'first_name'=> 'required',
                'sec_name'=>'required',
                'email'=> 'required|email',
                'password'         => 'required|min:8|max:24',
                'question-1' => 'required|int',
                'question-2' => 'required|int',
                'question-3' => 'required|int',
                'question-4' => 'required|int',
            ]);
```

Comment: thank You I forgot  this is big mistake from me

Comment: explain the problem to him, your answer requires educational explanation

Comment: @CoderMoataz - The problem is that validate method accepts array with validation rules which will be applied to the input parameters from the request. mt_rand(1,1000) is not a validation rule. Please check: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation